# operate in internet gateway mode to relay data - windows

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I want to write a general solution to relay data that comes from different application protocols to a proxy (socks and or/http) in order to do web filtering. Are there any open source projects for windows that do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out cntlm.  Here's the link:

http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

It's main selling point is that it does NTLM authentication, but it also works well as a general-purpose proxy.  It also has a gateway mode that allows it to proxy network traffic to another proxy server.